# Android: Proguard configuration to obfuscate class names and methods

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

As I know there are some classes which should not be obfuscated and also their names must persisted like 'Activities'. However I want other classes and packages inside my code be renamed. 
here is `build.gradle` inside app folder:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "apt.eve.good.morning"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

I use this proguard configuration for my application (`app\proguard-rules.pro`):

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-verbose

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
-allowobfuscations class *
# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {

   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}
```

It do optimization but as I checked inside my classses.dex all class names remained unchanged. So I want to know what I missed in my configuration file which is not obfuscating class/method names?

**P.S.1** I have searched several questions but I can't imagine what's wrong here.

**P.S.2** I have properly configured my android studio and changes on proguard configuration applies without no problem on my released .apk file.

Comment: post your gradle build file

Comment: Where do you check result of obfuscation? I'm not 100% sure, but I think in my project the obfuscated `.dex` files are in `build/intermediates/transforms/dex/**`, any other class/dex in `build/**` looks like output of build step before obfuscation. Ultimately the resulting `.apk`/`.aar` should be obfuscated, so if you are unzipping that one, and the the classes are not obfuscated, then something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Ped7g I use dex2jar to convert dex inside my apk to jar file. Then, I use [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-gui-overview) to decompile jar file and as I check there is no name obfuscation inside my code. all class,and packages remained with same name.

Comment: @Ped7g I tried to use an old version of jd-gui! new version shows obfuscated code correctly. It seems that everything was fine! Thanks for you notice.

Comment: oh, did I help? :D LOL, nice... (I was checking the result in text editor, usually for small `.dex` files you can judge by a 30-50s look at content whether it was obfuscated or not, the symbols are located more toward end of .dex/.class). Maybe it's a feature of jd-gui, to decrypt the obfuscated strings, if it find the unobfuscated .class/.dex elsewhere, or the .map file?

Comment: @Ped7g no it is not. I was using real old version. However wrap up your comments as an answer, to win the bounty!

Comment: @VSB: curiously enough.. isn't the older version then more powerful, disassembling more readable source from bytecode? ;) (actually if you are seasoned developer, the obfuscated symbol names are not a big drawback, the disassembled Java reads so nicely. Cracking games in assembler was like 2-3 leagues different story :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you check the obfuscated .dex files.

With common gradle build script the `build/**` folders may contain several unobfuscated versions of .dex/.class files.

Ultimately the resulting .apk/.aar should be obfuscated, so if you are unzipping that one, and the the classes are not obfuscated, then something doesn't work as expected.

As OP noted, it's also important to verify your [disassembly] tools work correctly.

Viewing binary form of .dex from .apk is usually enough to spot [un]obfuscated symbols (try with unobfuscated .class, the symbols are easily readable even in text editor, in obfuscated .dex the chain of symbols like "aa", "ab", ... is often well visible too).

Also running gradle proguard task manually with verbose option on may help to identify if the proguard was run and upon what files.

Comment: The petey suggestion to check the map file is much better, just make sure it's fresh (modify datetime == cca. build), and you can check easily all obfuscated symbols (and search for "sensitive" symbols to verify they were obfuscated, as expected). There's no need for any additional tool to get detailed overview of obfuscation success. (and my binary method can be used just to verify that .apk really contains expected result, as the map file suggests ... if you are  really paranoid).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your gradle file (`minifyEnabled=true`) and proguard config. You appear to be in good shape already.

To quickly confirm that your app obfuscating your classes,  check the resulting mapping.txt file when you make release builds.  This file "provides a translation between the original and obfuscated class, method, and field names."

Here is an example of a mapping.txt that obsfucates a hockeyapp library :

```
net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.AttachmentDownloader -> net.hockeyapp.android.d.a:
    java.util.Queue queue -> a
    boolean downloadRunning -> b
    67:67:net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.AttachmentDownloader getInstance() -> a
```

Lots more info can be found in the "Shrink Your Code and Resources" article here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you already changed

```
minifyEnabled=true
```

Inside app -> build.gradle?

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```